# How do I find the owner of a Google Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I know the name of a Firebase database, but I'm not a user with any rights for that database. I do have its project_id, private_key_id and private_key (from the code repository).

Is there a way to find out who the owner of the Firebase database is? (there are too many possibilities, to just directly ask people)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to look up the owner of a Firebase project publicly as that would be a pretty bad security risk.

If this is a project within the same organization, it might be ask to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) as they **may** be able to connect the owner to you in a secure way.

Comment: Complementing Frank's answer, the way Firebase works makes user authentication forced in order to execute the actions allowed according to their role, I recommend taking a look at this.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security#authentication
[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security